# Why are there some android phones which have no Google Play Services installed?

Tags: android

I am currently integrating Google Maps v2 and those are not running without Google Play Services. I know that I can check via

```
 GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable
```

But what is the reason that some phones have those services installed and some not?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question - more a case of why certain manufacturers make certain choices. I'd suggest asking it on android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason Google Play Services may not be avaialble:

1. User uses non-Play device (like Amazon Kindle Fire)
2. User disabled Google Play Services in apps settings menu.
3. User uninstalled Play Services on a rooted device.
4. User did a factory reset on older device. After reboot, Google Play Services may not be avaialble for some time (Google Play will install them eventually - in a couple of days. From the doc: `In general, devices running Android 2.2 (Froyo) or later and have the Google Play Store app installed receive updates within a few days`.

Comment: i have a Wildfire S device with android 2.3.5 which still got no google play services installed. how can that be? further we have a galaxy note 1 with android 4.0.4 with the same problem.

Comment: I only [found this](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) in a doc: `An old version of the Google Play Store app, which does not proactively download Google Play services updates, is present.` You can always download services manually [from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms).

Answer (score 0):

Some manufacturers have tried to create their own versions of Google Play. Amazon is a prime example of this.

Answer (score 0):

Some android phones uses custom roms which they don't include google play or any other google apps. You can install them if you are asking it.

Answer (score 0):

There are devices that are not certified by Google, such devices will not have the play services. Example Amazon android devices and some chinese devices. There is also another case such as my wife's Samsung Galaxy Y. Which has very low storage memory and there is none available now, so play services has never been installed itself on it.